# problems with my web store running by Joomla + Jomshopping

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, shopping-cart

My site: [AntikMania.ru](http://www.antikmania.ru)
It's an antique shop.
It works by jommla 2.5.14  + jomshopping 3.15 + it the shop 2 theme.
I have next problems:

1. A background of some object of main menu sometimes does not correspond with an open menu page.
2. The photos of the goods open in new page with adress like antikmania.ru/*/photo.jpg
   but I want to show hpotos using JS frame(like [here](http://demo.icetheme.com/it_theshop2/index.php/joomshopping/product/view/35/6))
3. How change the background of the buttons "Купить" (Buy)? Button label isn't visiable.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by the first point.

As for point 2, most likely reason why the photos are opening on a new page rather than via a Lightbox is because of a jQuery conflict. You have 2 versions of jQuery running on your page. one from the template and one from JoomShopping. I would suggest using [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327)

As for the "Buy" button, the colour for this is located in:

```
templates/it_theshop2/css/styles/style6.css
```

on line 94:

```
.button.button_cart {
    background-color: #738F65;
}
```

Comment: @StasShakirov - Have you set the Homepage as your default page?

Comment: of course. The situation like that dont depend on homepage.
it can occur with the second("Магазин") and the third ("Блог") mainmenu-pages.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. This is something to do with the menu you're using. You're using IceMenu I believe. This is something you will have to ask them about.